# How to Create a Spotify Playlist from a File

Tags: spotify, spotify-desktop

I have a text file I created using fb2k text tools; Artist Name - Song Name \n(new line)
This file includes my full music library, including 85k songs.
I'd like to somehow convert this to a single or multiple Spotify Playlists.
playlist-converter.net is doing one song per second, which means it is going to take roughly 24 hours to create this playlist on that site.

[image]

Is there any way i can do this locally using some github script or maybe a site that allows you to upload a file which will convert fairly quickly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if exists a ready-to-use script for this, but you can do it yourself, its not that hard if you know some programming language.

You can use Spotify API
https://developer.spotify.com/

For each line, you will have to call API with the name of song and Artist
https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/

So will return an JSON object, with the id of song.

For each id you will have to call api again, to include the new song
https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/add-tracks-to-playlist/

Thats it, good luck !